# nginx rewrite login and login/ in one statement

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Currently I'm using

```
location /login {
                rewrite ^/login/$ /login.php last;
                rewrite ^/login$ /login.php last;
}
```

to rewrite www.example.com/login and www.example.com/login/. I was wondering if this was also possible in one statement. I tried `rewrite ^/login(/)$ /login.php last;` but it didn't work.

Also I noticed since I started using rewrites that some of my css paths are broken because I used a relative paths. I will convert all of them to absolute paths but asked myself if there a more implications when using rewrites that I would need to be aware of.

EDIT:

This is how I handle the .php

```
location ~ \.php$ {
   if (!-f $request_filename) {
      return 404;
   }
   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   include fastcgi_params;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
location /login {
    rewrite ^/login/?$ /login.php last;
}
```

In RegEx, a question mark makes the preceding token optional.

Comment: Thanks quanta, I tried your solution but now the login.php will be downloaded when I enter www.example.com/login. Let me edit my post to show how I handle php..

Comment: I got it to work by removing the ~ in location to location /login {

Comment: `~` is only for case sensitive matching. In your case, `/login` is enough. But I wonder why you put a `~` causes error when parsing php.